# How do I delete a column that contains only zeros from a given row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've found how to remove column with zeros for all the rows using the command `df.loc[:, (df != 0).any(axis=0)]`, and I need to do the same but given the row number.

For example, for the folowing df

```
In [75]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,0,0], [1,0,1,0]], columns=['a','b','c','d'])

In [76]: df                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[76]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  0  0
1  1  0  1  0
```

Give me the columns with non-zeros for the row 0 and I would expect the result:

```
   a  b
0  1  1
```

And for the row 1 get:

```
   a  c
1  1  1
```

I tried a lot of combinations of commands but I couldn't find a solution.

**UPDATE:**

I have a 300x300 matrix, I need to better visualize its result.

Below a pseudo-code trying to show what I need

```
for i in range(len(df[rows])):
  _df = df.iloc[i]
  _df = _df.filter(remove_zeros_columns)
  print('Row: ', i)
  print(_df)
```

Result:

```
Row: 0
   a  b
0  1  1

Row: 1
   a  c  f
1  1  5  10

Row: 2
   e
2  20
```

Best Regards.
Kleyson Rios.

Comment: So how looks final DataFrame? Both rows together? What are new columns names?

Comment: @jezrael I have a very large dense matrix with a lot of zeros, I need to find a way to better see the values. I would like to loop the rows of the dataframe and write/append to a txt file the ith row with only the columns with values > 0. So, I need to slice the df by each row keeping the column names for non-zeros values.

Comment: To split this for one row you could use: (df.iloc[i] != 0), this might help you to iterate over all rows

Comment: @KleysonRios  when you see the first and second row of the example you have posted, the columns are a,c and a,d so how do you want the final df like? what are the column names there? can you post  sample expected output too?

Comment: So is possible different structure, like `df = df.reset_index().melt('index', var_name='columns').query('value != 0')` ?

Comment: For each ith row a need a new df showed in my question. My dataframe is a confusion matrix from a classification problem. I need to see row id with the columns names and their values for non-zeros.

Comment: you have to show sample output for whole dataframe

Comment: @Nihal not possible to have a final dataframe for the whole df. That's why I need a loop to select individual rows, filter the zeros columns and save this df* to a file, and then move to the next row. For each row I will have different columns, so not possible to put all together.

Comment: what are you trying to do by achieving this?, what is your end goal?

Comment: @Nihal I need to find a better way to visualize this very big matrix. For each row, which columns has some value and their values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change data structure:

```
df = df.reset_index().melt('index', var_name='columns').query('value != 0')
print (df)
   index columns  value
0      0       a      1
1      1       a      1
2      0       b      1
5      1       c      1
```

If need new column by values joined by `,` compare values for not equal by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and use matrix multiplication by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df['new'] = df.ne(0).dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
print (df)
   a  b  c  d   new
0  1  1  0  0  a, b
1  1  0  1  0  a, c
```

EDIT:

```
for i in df.index:
    row = df.loc[[i]]

    a = row.loc[:, (row != 0).any()]
    print ('Row {}'.format(i))
    print (a)
```

Or:

```
def f(x):
    print ('Row {}'.format(x.name))
    print (x[x!=0].to_frame().T)

df.apply(f, axis=1)

Row 0
   a  b
0  1  1
Row 1
   a  c
1  1  1
```

Comment: I dont need to see the original matrix. Is a matrix of 300x300. As just need to see the selected row with the non-zeros columns.

Comment: @KleysonRios - yes, so how should looks final output?

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])


def get(row):

    return list(df.columns[row.ne(0)])


df['non zero column'] = df.apply(lambda x: get(x), axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

also if you want single liner use this

```
df['non zero column'] = [list(df.columns[i]) for i in df.ne(0).values]
```

output

```
   a  b  c  d non zero column
0  1  1  0  0          [a, b]
1  1  0  1  0          [a, c]
```

Comment: Interesting but this solution is not a good solution for my case. I have almost 300 column. The visualization is not good and easy yet. Please see, my last comment in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question more strictly.
Just change the value of given_row as needed.

```
given_row = 1
mask_all_rows = df.apply(lambda x: x!=0, axis=0)
mask_row = mask_all_rows.loc[given_row]
cols_to_keep = mask_row.index[mask_row == True].tolist()
df_filtered = df[cols_to_keep]

# And if you only want to keep the given row
df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered.index == given_row]
```